# Switch with if, else if, else, and loops inside case

Tags: java

For the purpose of my question I've only included case 1, but the other cases are the same. Let's say value is currently 1, we go to case 1 and our for loop goes through the array to see if each element matches with the whatever_value variable. In this case if it does, we declare the value variable to be equal to 2, and we break out of the loop. The problem is that when i highlight the other break(in eclipse), it says that the breaks are attached to the for statement as well, but i only wanted the for statement to be attached to the if statement, not the else if statements as well. I thought because there are no brackets for the for statement that it would only loop for the if statement but eclipse says otherwise(else if also loops from 0 to the length of the array).

```
  switch (value) {
  case 1:
     for (int i = 0; i < something_in_the_array.length; i++)
        if (whatever_value == (something_in_the_array[i])) {
           value = 2;
           break;
        } else if (whatever_value == 2) {
           value = 3;
           break;
        } else if (whatever_value == 3) {
           value = 4;
           break;
        }
     break;
  case 2:

  // code continues....
```

Comment: Small piece of advice: Don't mix tabs and spaces. It'll ruin the formatting as you can clearly see.

Comment: because the for statement also loops the else if statement which i don't want but don't know how to make it so that only the if statement is looped. Therefore so that it doesn't loop the length of our array(IF the else if statement matches), i insert a break. It still loops the else if statement the entire length of our array if the else if statement doesn't match however. It's confusing and my code is confusing, I understand. My question is just how do i make it so that the if statement only, not else if get's looped.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem..... I think is that your for loop is encompassing all of the `if`, `else if` stuff - which acts like one statement, like hoang nguyen pointed out.

Change to this. Note the brackets that denote the code block on which the for loop operates and the change of the first `else if` to `if`.

```
switch(value){

    case 1:
        for(int i=0; i<something_in_the_array.length;i++) {
            if(whatever_value==(something_in_the_array[i])) {
                value=2;
                break;
             }
        }

        if(whatever_value==2) {
            value=3;
            break;
        }
        else if(whatever_value==3) {
            value=4;
            break;
        }
        break;


    case 2:

code continues....
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you, that's how you do it, i tried to bracket the if statement for the for loop but it wouldn't let me do to else if being attached to if. However if i do an if statement separate for the loop it i'll work like you showed. Thank you!

Comment: @eboix - *"// This is really like an else if because it will not be executed if the previous if statement was."* - Incorrect.  The `break` in the `for` loop breaks to the end of the loop.  And the next statement executed will be the following `if` statement!!

Comment: @StephenC What was I thinking.... you are completely correct. I don't even know how I was upvoted :P

Answer (score 3):

In this case, I'd recommend using break labels.

http://www.java-examples.com/break-statement

This way you can specifically call it outside of the for loop.

Comment: Cool solution! I didn't know these existed until today and I've been programming in Java for over 5 years.

Answer (score 2):

> but i only wanted the for statement to be attached to the if statement, not the else if statements as well.

Well get rid of the `else` then.  If the `else if` is not supposed to be part of the `for` then write it as:

```
           for(int i=0; i<something_in_the_array.length;i++)
                if(whatever_value==(something_in_the_array[i]))
                {
                    value=2;
                    break;
                }

           if(whatever_value==2)
           {
                value=3;
                break;  // redundant now
           }

           else if(whatever_value==3)
           {
                value=4;
                break;  // redundant now
           }
```

Having said that:

- it is not at all clear what you are really trying to do here,
- not having the `else` part in the loop doesn't seem to make a lot of sense here,
- a lot of people (myself included) think it is to always use braces ... so that people don't get tripped up by incorrect indentation when reading your code.  (And in this case, it might help us figure out what you are really trying to do here ...)

Finally, braces are less obtrusive if you put the opening brace on the end of the previous line; e.g.

```
  if (something) {
     doSomething();
  }
```

rather than:

```
  if (something) 
  {
     doSomething();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like kind of a homely way of doing things, but if you must...
you could restructure it as such to fit your needs:

```
boolean found = false;

case 1:

for (Element arrayItem : array) {
    if (arrayItem == whateverValue) {
        found = true;    
    } // else if ...
}
if (found) {
    break;
}
case 2:
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need the `for` statement to contain only the `if`, you need to remove its `else`, like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<something_in_the_array.length;i++)
    if(whatever_value==(something_in_the_array[i]))
    {
        value=2;
        break;
    }

    /*this "else" must go*/
    if(whatever_value==2)
    {
        value=3;
        break;
    }

    else if(whatever_value==3)
    {
        value=4;
        break;
    }
```